# Analysis to extract task flows from UI event log

Tags: user-interface, event-log

Given a table of UI events, how can I detect task flows, task loops, and behavioural patterns?

I'm instrumenting my software to track what the user does. Controls clicked, keys pressed, and so on, all timestamped. I want to extract several levels of information:

- Task flows: user clicks A, then B, then C to complete some task. Example: To edit a Wikipedia page, user clicks Edit, scrolls on the page, clicks in the editor, types, scrolls, and clicks "save".
- Task loops: users often repeat several low-level tasks. Example: to fine-tune formatting on a Wikipedia page, user Edits, then Previews, repeatedly before committing.
- Behavioural segmentation: given multiple users, correlate task and task loop patterns to extract user types. Example: "consumer" never edits, "expert" edits comprehensively on few pages, "editor" edits shallowly on many pages.

What analysis techniques can I use to detect event associations, task associations, and behavioural associations in my event log?